# ISPN000476: Timed out waiting for responses for request 73 from

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, caching, infinispan

while trying to use EmbeddedCacheManager from infinispan(9.4.11.Final) with below configuration, I get an exception on server.

```
/**
 * Configure infinispan to run with a default clustered jgroups setup.
 */
@Bean
public InfinispanGlobalConfigurer infinispanRemoteConfigurer(
        @Value("foo") String clusterName) {
    return () -> GlobalConfigurationBuilder
            .defaultClusteredBuilder()
            .transport()
            .clusterName(clusterName)
            .addProperty("configurationFile", "default-configs/default-jgroups-udp.xml")
            .globalJmxStatistics()
            .build();
}

/**
 * Configures the bar cache.
 */
@Bean(name = "bar")
public org.infinispan.configuration.cache.Configuration platformsCache() {
    return new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.REPL_SYNC)
            .memory().size(1000L)
            .memory().evictionType(EvictionType.COUNT)
            .build();
}

/**
 * Configures the bla cache.
 */
@Bean(name = "bla")
public org.infinispan.configuration.cache.Configuration undoStacksCache() {
    return new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.REPL_SYNC)
            .memory().size(1000L)
            .memory().evictionType(EvictionType.COUNT)
            .build();
}

/**
 * Configures the bla1.
 * This will never be clustered.
 */
@Bean(name = "bla1")
public org.infinispan.configuration.cache.Configuration arePlatformsCache() {
    return new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.LOCAL)
            .memory().size(1000L)
            .memory().evictionType(EvictionType.COUNT)
            .build();
}

/**
 * Configures the bla2.
 * Not intended to be clustered.
 */
@Bean(name = "bla2")
public org.infinispan.configuration.cache.Configuration areOperationsCache() {
    return new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.LOCAL)
            .memory().size(1000L)
            .memory().evictionType(EvictionType.COUNT)
            .build();
}
```

The exception trace are as below:

```
2019-10-14 18:35:37 [remote-thread--p2-t3] ERROR o.i.i.i.InvocationContextInterceptor - ISPN000136: Error executing command PutKeyValueCommand, writing keys [bar]
org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000299: Unable to acquire lock after 10 seconds for key bar and requestor CommandInvocation:XXX.XXX.XXX.XX-44468:4. Lock is held by CommandInvocation:XXX.XXX.XXX.XX-44468:3
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.impl.DefaultLockManager$KeyAwareExtendedLockPromise.get(DefaultLockManager.java:288)
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.impl.DefaultLockManager$KeyAwareExtendedLockPromise.get(DefaultLockManager.java:218)
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.impl.InfinispanLock$LockPlaceHolder.checkState(InfinispanLock.java:436)
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.impl.InfinispanLock$LockPlaceHolder.toInvocationStage(InfinispanLock.java:408)
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.impl.DefaultLockManager$KeyAwareExtendedLockPromise.toInvocationStage(DefaultLockManager.java:248)
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.impl.DefaultLockManager$KeyAwareExtendedLockPromise.toInvocationStage(DefaultLockManager.java:272)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.nonTxLockAndInvokeNext(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:294)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.visitNonTxDataWriteCommand(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.NonTransactionalLockingInterceptor.visitDataWriteCommand(NonTransactionalLockingInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:73)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.handleNonTxWriteCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:306)
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.handleWriteCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:252)
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:73)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheMgmtInterceptor.updateStoreStatistics(CacheMgmtInterceptor.java:214)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheMgmtInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(CacheMgmtInterceptor.java:179)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:73)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.handleDefault(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:73)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextAndExceptionally(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor.visitCommand(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.handleDefault(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:73)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.visitCommand(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.AsyncInterceptorChainImpl.invokeAsync(AsyncInterceptorChainImpl.java:234)
    at org.infinispan.commands.remote.BaseRpcInvokingCommand.processVisitableCommandAsync(BaseRpcInvokingCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan.commands.remote.SingleRpcCommand.invokeAsync(SingleRpcCommand.java:57)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.BasePerCacheInboundInvocationHandler.invokeCommand(BasePerCacheInboundInvocationHandler.java:117)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.BaseBlockingRunnable.invoke(BaseBlockingRunnable.java:99)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.BaseBlockingRunnable.runAsync(BaseBlockingRunnable.java:71)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.BaseBlockingRunnable.run(BaseBlockingRunnable.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2019-10-14 18:35:38 [remote-thread--p2-t3] WARN  o.i.r.i.NonTotalOrderPerCacheInboundInvocationHandler - ISPN000071: Caught exception when handling command SingleRpcCommand{cacheName='bar', command=PutKeyValueCommand{key=bar, successful=true, topologyId=13}}
org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000299: Unable to acquire lock after 10 seconds for key bar and requestor CommandInvocation:XXX.XXX.XXX.XX-44468:4. Lock is held by CommandInvocation:XXX.XXX.XXX.XX-44468:3
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.impl.DefaultLockManager$KeyAwareExtendedLockPromise.get(DefaultLockManager.java:288)
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.impl.DefaultLockManager$KeyAwareExtendedLockPromise.get(DefaultLockManager.java:218)
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.impl.InfinispanLock$LockPlaceHolder.checkState(InfinispanLock.java:436)
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.impl.InfinispanLock$LockPlaceHolder.toInvocationStage(InfinispanLock.java:408)
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.impl.DefaultLockManager$KeyAwareExtendedLockPromise.toInvocationStage(DefaultLockManager.java:248)
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.impl.DefaultLockManager$KeyAwareExtendedLockPromise.toInvocationStage(DefaultLockManager.java:272)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.nonTxLockAndInvokeNext(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:294)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.visitNonTxDataWriteCommand(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.NonTransactionalLockingInterceptor.visitDataWriteCommand(NonTransactionalLockingInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:73)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.handleNonTxWriteCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:306)
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.handleWriteCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:252)
    at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:73)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheMgmtInterceptor.updateStoreStatistics(CacheMgmtInterceptor.java:214)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheMgmtInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(CacheMgmtInterceptor.java:179)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:73)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.handleDefault(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:73)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextAndExceptionally(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor.visitCommand(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.handleDefault(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:73)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.visitCommand(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.AsyncInterceptorChainImpl.invokeAsync(AsyncInterceptorChainImpl.java:234)
    at org.infinispan.commands.remote.BaseRpcInvokingCommand.processVisitableCommandAsync(BaseRpcInvokingCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan.commands.remote.SingleRpcCommand.invokeAsync(SingleRpcCommand.java:57)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.BasePerCacheInboundInvocationHandler.invokeCommand(BasePerCacheInboundInvocationHandler.java:117)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.BaseBlockingRunnable.invoke(BaseBlockingRunnable.java:99)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.BaseBlockingRunnable.runAsync(BaseBlockingRunnable.java:71)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.BaseBlockingRunnable.run(BaseBlockingRunnable.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2019-10-14 18:35:43 [timeout-thread--p3-t1] ERROR o.i.i.i.InvocationContextInterceptor - ISPN000136: Error executing command PutKeyValueCommand, writing keys [bar]
org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000476: Timed out waiting for responses for request 15 from XXX.XXX.XXX.XX-44468
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.MultiTargetRequest.onTimeout(MultiTargetRequest.java:167)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.AbstractRequest.call(AbstractRequest.java:87)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.AbstractRequest.call(AbstractRequest.java:22)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2019-10-14 18:35:43 [timeout-thread--p3-t1] WARN  o.i.r.i.NonTotalOrderPerCacheInboundInvocationHandler - ISPN000071: Caught exception when handling command SingleRpcCommand
org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000476: Timed out waiting for responses for request 15 from XXX.XXX.XXX.XX-44468
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.MultiTargetRequest.onTimeout(MultiTargetRequest.java:167)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.AbstractRequest.call(AbstractRequest.java:87)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.AbstractRequest.call(AbstractRequest.java:22)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: The time out is perhaps taken as the default from the jgroup as defined in the xsd, when the configuration is programatically defined rather than declarative(using xml).

<xs:attribute name="remote-timeout" type="xs:long" default="${Clustering.remoteTimeout}">

So programtically, increased the remote-timout as 60 seconds 
/**
 * Configures the bar cache.
 */
@Bean(name = "bar")
public org.infinispan.configuration.cache.Configuration bar() {
    return new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.REPL_SYNC).remoteTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

Comment: What does the rest of the code look like? Key `bar` is updated, but no code above shown. It's odd for a lock not to be released in a non-transactional situation, like above.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://developer.jboss.org/message/991244?et=watches.email.thread#991244

Comment: This is the full code for the spring boot infinispan configuration in cluster mode. can you please tell me which part of the code you are looking for? is there a lock by default? do I need to make an explicit release of the lock?

Comment: The code that interacts with the cache, that puts data. Are you running some kind of load test? How many threads are involved in your test?

Comment: If not doing a load test, you should enable TRACE on `org.infinispan` and get some thread dumps before/after timeouts in all nodes to see what might be holding things. It's odd to see such situations these days.

Comment: I suggest running with `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`, IPv6 and UDP multicast have weird interactions (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-9345). Alternative workarounds are setting `<FRAG3 frag_size="1200"/>` or switching to TCP.